# ffmpeg splitting rgba into rgb and a and adding them next to each other in the output video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to split a gif into a rgb layer and a alpha layer and putting the outputs next to each other in a mp4.

`ffmpeg -i yB.gif -filter_complex "[0:v]alphaextract[a]; [0:v][a]hstack=inputs=2;"  test.mp4`

I always get the error message: No such filter: ''

Can anyone help me with this command?

Comment: You have a trailing semicolon in your filter list. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was the problem